# Postgresql equivalent of with(xlock, rowlock)

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I had a query in sql server which looks something like this:

```
DECLARE @someIncrementalField int;
set @someIncrementalField = select max(SomeField) from SomeTable with (xlock, rowlock) where field1 = 1 and field2 = 2 and field3 = 3;
```

the sql server table had a unique key index on field1, field2, field3.

The idea here was to lock the part of the table as per the index and select the max value and use max + 1 to insert in the same table.

Now I am trying to migrate to PostgreSql, How do I do this is postgres? I cannot do

```
FOR UPDATE
```

with aggregate select query. If I do

```
LOCK table IN ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE
```

will that lock the entire table or part of the table that is indexed using the fields?

EDIT: 
NOT DOING THIS FOR A SEQUENCE. I have a separate identity field on the table.

**EDIT 2:**

```
id  a   b(date)     c   trace
1   1   6/1/2016    1   100001
2   1   6/1/2016    1   100002
3   1   6/1/2016    1   100003
4   1   6/1/2016    1   100004
5   1   6/1/2016    2   100001
6   1   6/1/2016    2   100002
7   1   6/1/2016    3   100001
8   1   6/1/2016    3   100002
```

Lets say this is the table, the column trace rotates from 100000 - 999999. 
Next entry was (1, 6/1/2016, 1),

1. I want to lock the part of the table where a = 1, b = 6/1/2016, c = 1.
2. Get the max of the trace column from that part.
3. Add (1, 6/1/2016, 1, (max from step 2) + 1)
4. Release the lock.

When this is happening, I want other inserts and updates to go through just fine in other parts of the table.

Can I create a cycling sequence for the trace column based on a, b and c?

**EDIT 3**:  I would like to thank a_horse_with_no_name for explaining an approach about using the trigger. I learnt a lot from that. I first applied your solution then I installed the debugger and tried some other stuff and the following solution worked for me.

I did something like this to achieve what I was looking for. I use the pldbgapi(debugger) extension to make sure that it was not locking the entire table and there weren't any duplicate entry errors.

```
create or replace function insert_new(IN a_in integer, IN, b_in integer, IN c_in integer)
  returns integer
as
$func$
declare new_trace integer;
begin
  --this locks the max value until the function ends and other concurrent inserts would wait here until the function holding the lock is done
  perform trace from my_table where a=a_in and b=b_in and c=c_in order by trace desc limit 1 for update;
  select trace from my_table where a=a_in and b=b_in and c=c_in into new_trace order by trace desc limit 1;

  SELECT CASE WHEN new_trace IS 999999 THEN 100001 ELSE new_trace + 1 END INTO new_trace;
  insert into my_table values(a, b, c, new_trace);

  return query select new_trace;
end;
$func$
language plpgsql;
```

Comment: "*The idea here was to lock the part of the table as per the index and select the max value and use max + 1 to insert in the same table*" do ***NOT*** do that! It is not going to scale at all and will only work _correctly_  if you indeed lock the whole table. Why do you think you need that in the first place? Why not just use a sequence to generate IDs?

Comment: Have you heard of [`IDENTITY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) property in SQL Server.

Comment: I have a identity field on the table, this incremental field I am talking about is intended to be based on field1, field2(this is a date field) and field3 and it goes from 1...999999 and rotates again. Also not trying to lock the whole table at all. I am trying to lock part of the table where field1 = something, field2=something and field3= something and get the max of that incremental field.

Comment: If you use `max() + 1` to "generate" an ID value you **have** to lock the whole table, otherwise this will never work correctly, regardless if you just use it for a subset of rows - other transactions could have deleted/inserted rows which isn't visible to the transaction doing the `max()`. If you just need a "rotating number" use a sequence with the `cycle` attribute.

Comment: I understand that. Thank you for your time. May be the EDIT 2 would elaborate what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way you can achieve that without locking the whole table as that is the only way to prevent concurrent inserts that would mess up your `max() + 1` retrieval.

The only way I can think of is is to use some custom generator function that uses a separate table to generate the trace value.

```
create table trace_generator
(
   a_value integer not null, 
   b_value date not null,
   c_value integer not null,
   trace_value integer not null default 100000, 
   primary key (a_value, b_value, c_value)
);

insert into generator (a_value, b_value, c_value)
select distinct a,b,c
from the_table;
```

If you want, you can populate the `trace_generator` in an insert trigger for the base table if new combinations of (a,b,c) are inserted.

Now create a function that gets the next trace value:

```
create function next_value(p_aval integer, p_bval date, p_cval integer)
  returns integer
as
$$
  update trace_generator
     set trace_value = case 
                         when trace_value = 999999 then 100000 
                         else trace_value + 1 
                       end
  where a_value = p_aval
    and b_value = p_bval
    and c_value = p_cval
  returning trace_value;
$$
language sql;
```

If you want to generate the rows in the `trace_generator` table automatically for new combinations of `(a,b,c)` you could use an `insert on conflict update` inside that function instead of the plain update.

This will lock the row in the `generator` table but nothing in the base table. To insert a new row with a trace value you just call that function. That will block all other transactions that try to generate a new trace value for:

```
insert into the_table (a,b,c,trace)
values (1, date '2016-06-01', 1, next_value(1, date '2016-06-01', 1));
```

As long as the insert is not committed no other transaction can insert a row for that combination of a,b,c. If the insert is committed any waiting (next) transaction will see the incremented value. If the insert is rolled back, the next transaction will see the old value.

Unfortunately you can't make the call to `next_value()` a default value for the column because you are not allowed to reference other columns in a function for a default value. But you could put that into trigger to automate this:

```
create or replace function assign_trace()
  returns trigger
as
$$
begin
  new.trace_value := next_value(new.a_value, new.b_value, new.c_value);
  return new;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;

create trigger trace_trg
   before insert on the_table
   for each row execute procedure assign_trace();
```

Then the insert can be simplified to:

```
insert into the_table (a,b,c)
values (1, date '2016-06-01', 1);
```

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate example. I implemented your solution and it worked. I tried something else with the for update lock and tested it seem to work too. I added my solution to the EDIT.